# Merging mutliple pandas dfs time series on DATE index and which are contained in a python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that contains CLOSE prices for several stocks, stock indices, fixed income instruments and currencies (AAPL, AORD, etc.), using a DATE index. The different DFs in the dictionary have different lengths, i.e. some time series are longer than others. All the DFs have the same field, ie. 'CLOSE'.

The length of the dictionary is variable. How can I merge all the DFs into a single one, by DATE index, and also using lsuffix = partial name and feature of the the file I am reading? (for example, the AAPL_CLOSE.csv file has a DATE & a CLOSE field, but to differentiate from the other 'CLOSE' in the merged DF, its name should be AAPL_CLOSE)

This is what I have:

```
asset_name = []
files_to_test = glob.glob('*_CLOSE*')
for name in files_to_test:
    asset_name.append(name.rsplit('_', 1)[0])
```

Which returns:

```
asset_name = ['AAPL', 'AORD', 'EURODOLLAR1MONTH', 'NGETF', 'USDBRL']
files_to_test = ['AAPL_CLOSE.csv',
 'AORD_CLOSE.csv',
 'EURODOLLAR1MONTH_CLOSE.csv',
 'NGETF_CLOSE.csv',
 'USDBRL_CLOSE.csv']
```

Then:

```
asset_dict = {}
for name, file in zip(asset_name, files_to_test):
    asset_dict[name] = pd.read_csv(file, index_col = 'DATE', parse_dates = True)
```

This is the little function I would like to generalize, to create a big merge of all the DFs in the dictionary by DATE, using lsuffix = the elements in asset_list.

```
merged = asset_dict['AAPL'].join(asset_dict['AORD'], how = 'right', lsuffix ='_AAPL')
```

The DFs will have a lot of N/A due to the mismatch of lengths, but I will deal with that later.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787072/python-pandas-join-dataframes-on-index

Comment: Thank you. The question you point out is tangentially related; it does not address the merging of multiple dfs at the same time, but in pairs.

Comment: Just merge them in one at a time. That is the way that merges are generally written. Keep a "master" dataframe at all times (at first this is just the first dataframe) and then merge the other ones into that one by one.

Comment: One at a time if very inefficient. I am half-way into a solution and I'll probably answer my own question if I don't see the right answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After not getting any answers, I found a solution that works, although there might be better ones. This is what I did:

```
asset_dict = {}
for name, file in zip(asset_name, files_to_test):
    asset_dict[name] = pd.read_csv(file, index_col='DATE', parse_dates=True)
    asset_dict[name].sort_index(ascending = True, inplace = True)
```

Pandas can [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) multilple dfs (at once, not one by one) contained in dictionaries, 'straight out of the box' without much tweaking, by specifying the axis and other parameters.

```
df = pd.concat(asset_dict, axis = 1)
```

The resulting df is a multi-index df, which is a problem for me. Also, the time series for stock prices are all of different lengths, which creates a lot of NaNs. I solved bot problems with this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Now, the columns of my df are these:

```
['AAPL', 'AORD', 'EURODOLLAR1MONTH', 'NGETF', 'USDBRL']
```

But since I wanted them to contain the 'STOCK_CLOSE' format, I do this:

```
old_columns = df.columns.tolist()
new_columns = []
for name in old_columns:
    new_name = name + '_CLOSE_'
    new_columns.append(new_name)
```